# What exactly does ++array[s.charAt(i) - 'A'] do?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) 
    {
        if (s.charAt(i) >= 'A' && s.charAt(i) <= 'Z') 
        {
            ++array[s.charAt(i) - 'A'];
        }
    }
```

I understand the For loop. the s.length() is 26, int[26] to be exact. so this loop will occur 26 times, 0-25. If the Char at i, 0-25 is between or are A-Z it will then proceed to `++array[s.charAt(i) - 'A'];` From what i see it adds array once per loop, or adds the value of array once per loop, for the String at char i so the first one would be 0 second would be 2,  because arrays start at 0. so adding an array at location of `i -'A'` is where i get confused.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The statement `++array[s.charAt(i) - 'A'];` is incrementing the value in the array indexed by `s.charAt(i) - 'A'`.

What this loop does is that it counts up the number of occurrences of each letter in `s`.

The reason for `- 'A'`, is that it "shifts" the ascii/unicode value so that `A - Z` have values 0 - 25. And are thus more suitable as an array index.

Answer (score 20):

`array` seems to be a "counter per capital letter". By subtracting character `'A'` from an arbitrary character in a string, you get the letter's index in the array:

```
'A' - 'A' == 0
'B' - 'A' == 1
'C' - 'A' == 2
```

To understand this, you should understand, that Java treats `char` the same as (unsigned) `short`. Hence, you can make calculations with `char`

Answer (score 2):

What is count[str.charAt(i)]++ actually storing? [duplicate]
for those guys who have the same related question here is the answer

**First**

*static final int chars=256;
static char count[]=new char[chars];*

when we change this code into image it become like this

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  97  ..  255

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

**Second**

*count[str.charAt(i)]++;*

Let say you have str = “abc”
Then str.charAt(0) will be “a”
Then count[‘a’] means count[97] why? Because java automatically converted ‘a’ into ASCII code number 97;
Then count[97] value is 0 when you increment it like this count[97]++ then it will become 1

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  97  ..  255

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0

if you increment it again like count[97]++ then it will become 2.

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  97  ..  255

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0

That is the whole the secret behind. I do not describe the rest because I think your question is answered.
If you want to test what I said is correct check it using this simple code

public static void main(String[] argv)
{

```
 int[] count = new int[255]; 
    count['a']++;
    System.out.println(count['a']);
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<count.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(counter++ + " " + count[i]);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

count chars

(count chars is not a historical figure)

Answer (score 1):

```
++array[s.charAt(i) - 'A'];
```

count frequency of each character in given string s and store the frequency of each character at a particular index in the array.